# NewBee on NodeJs or PhantomJS: Function names on Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just learning NodeJS and/or PhantonJS. 
As a programmer with a lot of C experience, I do not like the way NodeJs code is written and find it a bit messy/unreadable. (Sorry if I ruffled any feathers)

In spirit of cleaning up the code, I was trying to do this and found a block.
In C or C++, we should be able to pass a function by name but in NodeJS/PhantomJS it does not seem to work. 
Am I doing somthing wrong ?
Can someone explain to me how this is looked at by the Javascript interpreter ?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var printS = function (s) {
   console.log(s);
   phantom.exit();
} 

/* This works */
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function (s) {
   console.log(s);
   phantom.exit();
});

/* This does not work
  page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', printS(status));
*/

/*But this works 
  page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function (s) { printS(s);} );
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', printS(status));
```

fails because you're not passing the function but rather the result of invoking the function on `status`. If you want to pass the function, you'd do it this way

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', printS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be helpful to have a more extensive explanation. Let's start simple:

In JavaScript, we have **values** and **variables**. Variables are containers for values. Almost everywhere where we can use values, we can use variables.

In JavaScript source code, we express values through *literals*, e.g. the number literal `42`. We can directly pass that value to a function:

```
f(42);
```

Additionally, instead of passing the value directly, we can pass a variable to the function:

```
var v = 42;
f(v);
```

That is, we can substitute values with variables.

---

Lets consider

```
var printS = function() { ... };
```

This clearly is a variable whose value is a function. If we'd *directly* pass that value to a function (i.e. we pass a function to a function), it would look like:

```
f(function() { ... }); // similar to f(42)
```

That's exactly what you have in your first case:

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function (s) {
    // ...
});
```

Since we know that we can replace values with variables, we can just substitute `function() { ... }` with `printS`:

```
var printS = function() { ... }; // similar to var v = 42;
f(printS); // similar to f(v)
```

So your example would become

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', printS);
```

---

What is wrong with

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', printS(status));
```

then?

Notice that you added additional characters after `printS`, namely `(status)`. They don't appear in the your first example where you inlined the function:

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function (s) {
    // ...
});
```

There is no `(status)` here. Hence these two constructs cannot be **not equivalent**.

`page.open` accepts a *function value* as second argument, but `printS(status)` doesn't evaluate to the function `printS`, it *calls* the function `printS` and passes the *return value* to `page.open`.

---

Why does

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function (s) { printS(s);} );
```

work?

Lets remove the content and the argument of the function, and it becomes:

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function () { ... } );
```

That looks exactly like one of the examples above. `function () { ... }`, is a function literal, so to speak. It creates a function value. There are no `(...)` after it which would *call* the function.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work as you hope because page.open wants a function as its second argument... this callback pattern is very common in JavaScript. In your doesn't-work example, printS is being called with status as its argument, and it returns undefined. As undefined is not a function, it doesn't behave as you wish.

In your browser console or the node repl:

```
> printS = function (s) { console.log(s); };
function (s) { console.log(s); }
> typeof printS('hi');
hi
"undefined"
> typeof function (s) { printS(s); };
"function"
```

Another thing to know about JavaScript is that its dynamic typing and fairly generous type coercion can result in baffling behavior with no helpful errors to point you towards the root cause of your problem. A debugger or copious use of console.log() is frequently helpful in understanding these sort of problems.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Your explanation has been helpful.